# ListPlot Presentation

Tags: plotting

I would like to show the all the values on the horizontal axis. The default is an increment by 2. I am wanting to show 0 to 9 on the horizontal by increment of one so I can see the values aren't shown 1,3,5,7,9

```
a = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17};
b = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18};
ListPlot[{a, b}, PlotLabel -> "List ", 
PlotMarkers -> {●, ▲}, 
PlotLegends -> {A, B}, GridLines -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
DataRange -> All]
```

Comment: `DataRange -> {0, 9}`  ( or more likely you want `{0,8}` )

Answer (score 1):

```
FrameTicks -> {{Range[20], None}, {Range[9], None}}
```

or

```
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Range[9], None}}
```

`DataRange -> {0,9}` or `DataRange -> {0,8}` set the proper range but do force the ticks to be incremented by 1.